# How to avoid receiving events from the Process class in the wrong order?

Tags: .net, process, f#, race-condition

Let's say I want to write a program that calls another program, whose output contains both `stdout` output and `stderr` output.

For example, this program I call would be the F# compiler trying to compile an F# file containing errors:

```
F# Compiler for F# 4.0 (Open Source Edition)
Freely distributed under the Apache 2.0 Open Source License

/builds/someLib.fs(27,42): error FS0001: Type mismatch. Expecting a
    string * string    
but given a
    string * string * 'a    
The tuples have differing lengths of 2 and 3
```

(The first two lines are being printed to `stdout`, the rest to `stderr`.)

So I write a program that deals with the process class this way:

```
type OutChunk = StdOut of string | StdErr of string
type OutputBuffer = list<OutChunk>
type ProcessResult = { ExitCode: int; Output: OutputBuffer }

module Process =

let Execute (command: string, args: string, hidden: bool)
    : ProcessResult =

    // I know, this shit below is mutable, but it's a consequence of dealing with .NET's Process class' events
    let outputBuffer = new System.Collections.Generic.List<OutChunk>()
    let outputBufferLock = new Object()

    use outWaitHandle = new AutoResetEvent(false)
    use errWaitHandle = new AutoResetEvent(false)

    let startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(command, args)
    startInfo.UseShellExecute <- false
    startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput <- true
    startInfo.RedirectStandardError <- true

    use proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process()
    proc.StartInfo <- startInfo

    let outReceived (e: DataReceivedEventArgs): unit =
        if (e.Data = null) then
            outWaitHandle.Set() |> ignore
        else
            if not (hidden) then
                Console.WriteLine(e.Data)
            lock outputBufferLock (fun _ -> outputBuffer.Add(OutChunk.StdOut(e.Data)))

    let errReceived (e: DataReceivedEventArgs): unit =
        if (e.Data = null) then
            errWaitHandle.Set() |> ignore
        else
            if not (hidden) then
                Console.Error.WriteLine(e.Data)
            lock outputBufferLock (fun _ -> outputBuffer.Add(OutChunk.StdErr(e.Data)))

    proc.OutputDataReceived.Add outReceived
    proc.ErrorDataReceived.Add errReceived

    proc.Start() |> ignore
    let exitCode =
        try
            proc.BeginOutputReadLine()
            proc.BeginErrorReadLine()
            proc.WaitForExit()
            proc.ExitCode
        finally
            outWaitHandle.WaitOne() |> ignore
            errWaitHandle.WaitOne() |> ignore
    { ExitCode = exitCode; Output = List.ofSeq(outputBuffer) }

let rec PrintToScreen (outputBuffer: OutputBuffer) =
    match outputBuffer with
    | [] -> ()
    | head::tail ->
        match head with
        | StdOut(out) -> Console.WriteLine(out)
        | StdErr(err) -> Console.Error.WriteLine(err)
        PrintToScreen(tail)
```

However, even if I used locks in the code above to prevent race conditions when writing to the mutable List, sometimes when I run the F# program that calls the F# compiler, and then I call the `PrintToScreen` function, I get the streams intermixed:

```
F# Compiler for F# 4.0 (Open Source Edition)

/builds/someLib.fs(27,42): error FS0001: Type mismatch. Expecting a
Freely distributed under the Apache 2.0 Open Source License
    string * string    
but given a
    string * string * 'a    
The tuples have differing lengths of 2 and 3
```

(As you can see, the license text should have arrived before the compiler error!, but it didn't)

How can this be possible? How to deal with the diabolic `System.Diagnostics.Process` class to receive the streams/events in the correct order?

Comment: The problem is probably with buffering differences.  Try seeing stdout and stderr to buffer in the same way

Comment: they are buffering in the same way already (as far as I understand), so not sure what do you propose?

Comment: Normally error is unbuffered while output is buffered.  There is an option to change this, somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

This is likely a case of output buffering.
Have you tried calling `Console.Out.Flush()` and `Console.Error.Flush()` after writing to `stdout` and `stderr` respectively?